# Using tf.keras in TF 2.0, how can I define a custom layer that depends on the learning phase?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I want to build a custom layer using tf.keras. For simplicity, suppose it should return inputs*2 during training and inputs*3 during testing. What is the correct way to do this?

I tried this approach:

```py
class CustomLayer(Layer):
    @tf.function
    def call(self, inputs, training=None):
        if training:
            return inputs*2
        else:
            return inputs*3
```

I can then use this class like this:

```
>>> layer = CustomLayer()
>>> layer(10)
tf.Tensor(30, shape=(), dtype=int32)
>>> layer(10, training=True)
tf.Tensor(20, shape=(), dtype=int32)
```

It works fine! However, when I use this class in a model, and I call its `fit()` method, it seems that `training` is not set to `True`. I tried to add the following code at the beginning of the `call()` method, but `training` is always equal to 0.

```py
if training is None:
    training = K.learning_phase()
```

What am I missing?

**Edit**

I found a solution (see my answer), but I'm still looking for a nicer solution using `@tf.function` (I prefer autograph to this `smart_cond()` business). Unfortunately, it looks like `K.learning_phase()` does not play nice with `@tf.function` (my guess is that when the `call()` function gets traced, the learning phase gets hard-coded into the graph: since this happens before the call to the `fit()` method, the learning phase is always 0). This may be a bug, or perhaps there's another way to get the learning phase when using `@tf.function`.

Answer (score 2):

François Chollet confirmed that the correct solution when using `@tf.function` is:

```py
class CustomLayer(Layer):
    @tf.function
    def call(self, inputs, training=None):
        if training is None:
            training = K.learning_phase()
        if training:
            return inputs * 2
        else:
            return inputs * 3
```

There's currently a bug (as of Feb 15th 2019) that makes `training` always equal to `0`, but this will be fixed shortly.

Answer (score 0):

The following code does not use `@tf.function`, so it does not look as nice (since it does not use autograph), but it works fine:

```py
from tensorflow.python.keras.utils.tf_utils import smart_cond

class CustomLayer(Layer):
    def call(self, inputs, training=None):
        if training is None:
            training = K.learning_phase()
        return smart_cond(training, lambda: inputs * 2, lambda: inputs * 3)
```